# Некорректно обрабатываются нажатия клавиш js

Tags: javascript, события

в моей программе не сохраняется порядок нажатий клавиш. В поле  находится один текст, а в отладчике в переменной, которая хранит набранный текст, хранится несколько иное значение.

[в отладчике:   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk36v.png) [в input [image: введите сюда описание изображения]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYO90.png).

Стоит отметить, что правильно регистрируется где-то 99 процентов нажатий. Но для меня этого, конечно, же не достаточно.

Код представленный ниже я сократил по-максимуму, надеюсь на вашу помощь. Спасибо.

**main.js**

```js
let inputText = document.getElementsByClassName("text-panel")[0];
// набранный текст
let typedText = "";

function keyHandler(e) {
    typedText = typedText + e.key;
    let len = typedText.length;
    if (typedText == currentText) {
        showTotalSpeed();
    }
}
inputText.addEventListener("keyup", keyHandler);
```

**index.html**

```html
<input type="text" class="col-6 offset-3 text-panel"
          placeholder="Введите текст, расположенный выше" autocomplete="off" disabled>
```

Comment: Слишком вы по максимуму сократили код ))) Как минимум нужна html разметка и  событие, которое вешается на элемент и как оно вешается.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я немного подправил

Comment: Вы регистрируете отпускание клавиш, в не ввод текста. Отпускания могут отличаться. Например долго зажатая клавиша напишет несколько символов. А клавиши вставки из буфера вообще не соответствует тексту. Почему вам важен keyup, а не событие input и чтение из инпута?

Comment: @PavelGrishaev Вы были правы. Если вы напишете ответ, я дам вам галку. Большое спасибо, я очень долго искал эту ошибку.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev, можете подсказать как узнать keyCode у нажатой клавиши, я не могу найти этого поля в inputEvent.

Comment: @РусланМамедов событие input срабатывает не только от клавиш, а от любого ввода. Например от вставки из буфера мышкой через контекстное меню. Вам нужно сравнивать текст до изменений и после, чтобы определить символ или новый кусок строки, или чтобы определить удаление куска. Также вы можете использовать события вместе - keydown для определения клавиши, и input для надежности получения данных.

Comment: Задача просто ваша похожа на тренажёр набора :) . Если вы считаете количество символов в минуту например, то можно считать это на основе введённых кусков текста, а не именно "поклавишно". Ну а клавиши подсвечивать на экране по событиям нажатия/отпускания.